# Android Extending View and creating from XML Null pointer exception

Tags: xml, android, view

I've created a custom view by extending View, it draws fine but When i try and refer to the object in the xml so I can say add a touch listener if reports a null pointer exception. My xml file is extremely simple

```
<com.projector.interaction.layout.MapMouseView2
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mouse"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</com.projector.interaction.layout.MapMouseView2>
```

I then try and referene the View by

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.testlayout);
        MapMouseView2 view = (MapMouseView2)findViewById(R.id.mouse);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("Debug","Touch Not Working");
                return true;
            }
        }); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error","Error in TestActivity",e);
    }

}
```

But it gives me a null pointer exception. Then only fix I can find is to wrap my view in the xml file inside a LinearLayout and reference the view by

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.testlayout);

        LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin);
        MapMouseView2 mouseView = (MapMouseView2)lay.getChildAt(0);
        mouseView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("Debug","Touch Not Working");
                return true;
            }
        }); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error","Error in TestActivity",e);
    }

}
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong???

The View class is here

```
public class MapMouseView2 extends View{


WindowManager mWinMgr;
Rect zoom;
Rect panLeftRight;
Rect panUpDown;



public MapMouseView2(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context);
    Log.d("Debug","Context,AttribyteSet");
    try {
        mWinMgr = (WindowManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        zoom = new Rect(0, 0, 45, mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
        panLeftRight = new Rect(0, 458, mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),
                mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
        panUpDown = new Rect(mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 45, 0,
                mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), mWinMgr
                .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
        Log.d("Debug","Leaving Constructor");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error","Error in MapMouseView",e);
    }
}




protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    try {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        // make the entire canvas white
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(zoom, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(panLeftRight, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(panUpDown, paint);
        //canvas.drawCircle(x,y,30,threadPaint);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error","Exception in OnDraw",e);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Do you get a NPE when trying to view the layout in Eclipse? or When you run the app. Getting an NPE when trying to view the layout is no big deal. It happens alot with custom views.

Comment: it was when I run the app, it's all working now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should call `super(context, attrs);` in constructor of `MapMouseView2`.

**edit:**

If you don't do that your view doesn't get id.

In the second approach you refer to the view by position not name, so it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked a treat. Originally as originally I was extending LinearLayout and calling super(context,attrs) followed by 

LayoutParams layoutparams = generateLayoutParams(attrs);  this.setLayoutParams(layoutparams); but this didnt work either.

Thanks again, id spent hours trying to find a soloution and was about to go insane